# Export a list of Integrated Addresses from GUI (or monerod)?

Tags: integrated-address

Is there an easy way to spit out 100 or so integrated addresses from the GUI or command line into a csv or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wallet RPC interface has [a `make_integrated_address` command](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#make_integrated_address) that you can call repeatedly to do that.